# Openlayers.js JDK8 WILDFLY error js :handler is not a constructor / this.handler = new handler(this, this.callbacks, this.handlerOptions);

Tags: java-8, migration, openlayers, wildfly-16

I'm using OpenLayers.js v2.11 to manage geographical maps. My project is on JDK 6 + GlassFish, and everything works fine.

After migrating to Java 8 and WildFly, an error is reported in the OpenLayers.js code. This call

```
this.handler = new handler(this, this.callbacks, this.handlerOptions);
```

generates the following error: 'handler is not a constructor.'

Normally, JavaScript errors shouldn't depend on the JDK. But could this issue occur when transitioning from GlassFish to WildFly?

After replacing the call with

```
this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler(this, this.callbacks, this.handlerOptions);,
```

the error is corrected. However, I want to understand why there was no error in the same project with JDK 6 and GlassFish.

This call appears in the following method:

```
initialize: function(layer, handler, options) {
        OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(this, [options]);
        this.callbacks = OpenLayers.Util.extend(
            {
                done: this.drawFeature,
                modify: function(vertex, feature) {
                    this.layer.events.triggerEvent(
                        "sketchmodified", {vertex: vertex, feature: feature}
                    );
                },
                create: function(vertex, feature) {
                    this.layer.events.triggerEvent(
                        "sketchstarted", {vertex: vertex, feature: feature}
                    );
                }
            },
            this.callbacks
        );
        this.layer = layer;
        this.handlerOptions = this.handlerOptions || {};
        this.handlerOptions.layerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults(
            this.handlerOptions.layerOptions, {
                renderers: layer.renderers, rendererOptions: layer.rendererOptions
            }
        );
        if (!("multi" in this.handlerOptions)) {
            this.handlerOptions.multi = this.multi;
        }
        var sketchStyle = this.layer.styleMap && this.layer.styleMap.styles.temporary;
        if(sketchStyle) {
            this.handlerOptions.layerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults(
                this.handlerOptions.layerOptions,
                {styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({"default": sketchStyle})}
            );
        }
        this.handler = new handler(this, this.callbacks, this.handlerOptions);
    },
```

Thank you

Replace new handler by new OpenLayers.Handler works fine